# How to solve this error --> Error during the initialization of the SDK! DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, in that I am implementing Microblink https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microblink/blinkcard-in-browser-sdk npm for scanning credit cards but when I run the project it is showing this kind of error Error during the initialization of the SDK! DOMException: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope'

Please help to resolve this issue.

This is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import * as BlinkCardSDK from "@microblink/blinkcard-in-browser-sdk";
import './App.css';


const App = () => {
  if (BlinkCardSDK.isBrowserSupported()) {
    const loadSettings = new BlinkCardSDK.WasmSDKLoadSettings("sRwAAAYJbG9jYWxob3N0r/lOPmg/w35CpOHWK+o8YBgy/pGDcaB7TnbwT8mPpSzcCTWnV/AEyEIWVrcjyzdUSYb2bT0ccHxN4WDKrHoxoLQKBeq+ZukLOK13VwZXeikV4ggv2wrrW162/GIO5hajgqiEATKco+QfglS+OwguBweuacsuRR8UCD/YTdg4ysGMVljN7IIrthHPnmUa0SBOoeReXYvGmrKkVztIZzu9qkZoHu0UwCTN9Xloxa9Srw==");

    BlinkCardSDK.loadWasmModule(loadSettings).then
      (
        (wasmSDK: BlinkCardSDK.WasmSDK) => {
        },
        (error: any) => {
          // console.log('test')
          console.log("Error during the initialization of the SDK!", error);
          // console.log('testnew')
        }
      )
  }
  else {
    console.log("This browser is not supported by the SDK!");
  }
  return (
    <div>
    </div>
  )
}



export default App
```

If you have any questions please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the license key, you also need to set the proper absolute path to the actual wasm and js support files of the SDK, a.k.a the `engineLocation`. The resource files need to be hosted somewhere accessible to the app.

There's a more detailed explanation of the SDK configuration in the [documentation](https://github.com/blinkcard/blinkcard-in-browser#-configuration-of-sdk)

Quick side note: it's probably not recommended to share your license key publicly, even if it's just a trial key.